At night vs in night
I believed that 'at' was the only preposition to be used before 'night' till  on searching I found out that 'in night' is also possible.
https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/121858/at-night-or-in-the-night
Could someone please clarify the meaning of the prepositions "in" and "at" before night?"
Also, which among the following prepositions are appropriate for the sentence mentioned below?
She sat still _____ the night.

At
In
During
Throughout


In night is not possible - it's in the night, which could mean 'at night' or 'during a particular night'.

"...till I searched this up and found out that 'in night' is also possible." If you can edit to tell more about what gave you this impression, we can give more helpful answers that might explain why the impression is wrong.

I’m voting to close this question because it's based on the false premise that answers to the earlier question At Night or In the Night? somehow endorse the construction in night. Which is not idiomatically valid in English, so obviously they don't.

Noctural animals are active at night.
The people on deck heard the sound of a ship passing them in the night.
The anxious parents stayed by the bedside of their feverish child throughout the night.
At some time during the night the bank was robbed.

"in the night" means out there, in the darkness something is happening. "throughout the night" means an action is happening all of the night. "During the night" means at some point in the night this action happened.

I agree with all of TimR’s examples, but I can’t upvote the answer because OP asks for an explanation. In that sense, @WendyG’s comment is a significant fleshing out of this answer.

Then, should it be She sat still 'throughout' the night?

@Kakiaririki That statement has so little context that the only preposition that would be clearly wrong is at.

@TimR it seems to me that 'during' and 'in' are both synonymous. Is there any difference?

@Kakiaririki  in doesn't have temporal meaning, at least not without the help of some additional phrases like "At some time in the night" or "in the course of the night".  One could say "in the inky darkness of the night" and refer to night not temporally but as a condition or environment or situation.

Generally, 'in' would only be used with the definite article 'in the night', which means 'in the darkness (of night)'. This goes for the other prepositions too, 'at night' excepted. The classic example is the cliché 'ships that passed in the night'. Other examples would be 'he took cover in the night', or 'they heard an owl hoot in the night'.
A quick search of Google books shows that 'in night' has been used in various book titles, but such usage is not normal. The author has made a conscious decision not to use conventional practice. (eg. The book "Wolf in Night".)
The other exceptions are

Where 'night' is being used like a proper name (again in literary contexts): 'In Night's City'.
Where 'night' is used as part of a noun phrase: 'visual requirements in night driving'.

